# How can I fix the Class 'Album\Controller\AlbumController' not found error?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm newbie in Zend Framework 2. I created the folder structure and paste the code snippets from this page http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/routing-and-controllers.html about routing in Zend Framework 2.

I get the following error:

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Class 'Album\Controller\AlbumController' not found in C:\wamp\www\zend\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager.php on line 178
```

Below is my classmap_autoload.php

```
<?php 
return array();
```

Below is the Module.php

```
namespace Album;

class Module {
    public function getAutoloaderConfig(){
        return array(
            'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array(
                __DIR__.'/autoload_classmap.php',
            ),
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'namespace' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__.'/src/'.__NAMESPACE__,
                ),
            ),
        );
    }

    public function getConfig(){
        return include __DIR__.'/config/module.config.php';
    }

}
```

I have my `AlbumController` class already in the `module/Album/`
[image]

Here is my `module.config.php` from the Album module:

```
<?php 

return array(
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Album\Controller\Album' => 'Album\Controller\AlbumController',
        ),
    ),

     // The following section is new and should be added to your file
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'album' => array(
                'type'    => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/album[/:action][/:id]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Album\Controller\Album',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),

    'view_manager' => array(
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            'album' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
);
```

AlbumCOntroller.php

```
<?php


namespace Album\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class AlbumController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
    }

    public function addAction()
    {
    }

    public function editAction()
    {
    }

    public function deleteAction()
    {
    }
}
```

I have no idea why I have such an error.. I would like to learn what is happening inside Zend before rendering a page but before I intend to solve this problem ..
How can I fix this?

Comment: Please provide `Module.php`'s `getAutoloaderConfig()` and maybe also your `classmap_autoload.php` - The image may well be editted to be hosted elsewhere ;)

Comment: Hmm, is the `namespace` and `class` correctly defined inside `AlbumController.php`? That'd be my last guess currently :S

Comment: I have provided the AlbumCOntrolelr as well. However, I have no idea how to debug this .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Module.php `'namespace' => array` must be `namespaces` (in plural)

Also you can compare your code with https://github.com/zendframework/zf2-tutorial

Comment: Thanks alot. I was wasting hours to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently playing with the tutorial and integrated doctrine use. The above issue can show up with 'namespaces', probably after calling composer for an update, because ActionController's name seems to magically have been changed to `AbstractActionController`.

Without warning.

**edit**
I realized after inspection that the doctrine code was dated, so by pasting in a replacement, the controller name became out of date.